# How to shrink dynamic graph to fit into print page?

Tags: html, css, nvd3.js

Dynamic graph(size may increase/decrease based on user selection) is available and I am trying to print it both in portrait and landscape mode. While trying to print I am not able to view the entire graph. Its view is going out of the print page. When I zoom I am able to view the entire graph but it even goes to very smaller size based on the width of the graph displayed.

Is there any way to fit the entire graph to the size of the print page?

```
@media print and (orientation: landscape/portrait) {
   .graph{
    width:?
```

}
}

Comment: post some code, please